# SQL server Invalid Column name Invalid object name

Tags: sql, sql-server, object

I'm having a problem with a table I created. I am trying to run a query however a red line appears under my code ('excursionID', and 'excursions'), claiming 'Invalid Column name 'excursionID' and 'Invalid object name 'dbo.excursions' even though I have created the table already!

Here is the query

```
    SELECT 
        excursionID

    FROM [dbo].[excursions]
```

Here is the query I used to create the table

```
    USE [zachtravelagency]
    CREATE TABLE excursions (
        [excursionID] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
        [companyName] NVARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
        [location] NVARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
        [description] NVARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
        [date] DATE NOT NULL,
        [totalCost] DECIMAL NOT NULL,
```

I've tried dropping the table and inserting table again.

For some reason all my other tables work, it's just this table that doesn't identify itself. I'm very new to SQL so thank you for your patience!

Comment: you just need to update your intellisense cache. ctrl+shift+r

Comment: Cheers mate- told you I was new!

Comment: i have created table and dropped and recreated it's working fine @user3545833

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use DB [zachtravelagency] for create table.And You dont use this DB in your query. Default used db master in SSMS. Try

```
SELECT 
    excursionID

FROM [zachtravelagency].[excursions]
```